# SpringBoot Rest response not deserialiazed with jackson

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I am a running a project with SpringBoot. In this project I am calling an external Rest Service. I have modeled the response items into bean.
But when I get the response back the data are not serialised into the beans.
I guess there must be some configuration missing but I cannot find what.

I have added onfiguration spring-boot-starter-test to the configuration of Maven:

The rest client:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RestClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        assert(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetEmployee() {
        RestTemplate template = restTemplate.build();;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        List<MediaType> types = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        types.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        types.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        headers.setAccept(types);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer gWRdGO7sUhAXHXBnjlBCtTP");
        HttpEntity<Items> entity = new HttpEntity<Items>(headers);

        String uri = "https://mytest.com/employees";

        //ResponseEntity<String> rec = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        //System.out.println("Received: " + rec);


        ResponseEntity<Items> rec = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Items.class);
        System.out.println("Received: " + rec);
    }
}
```

When I inspect the elements of the response it, I get a list, all the items are with null values

```
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
    public class Item implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private String email;
    @JsonProperty
    private String phone;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}


@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public class Items implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Do you see what I am missing here?

The response is like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "item": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "string",
        "email": "string",
        "phone": "string",
```

Do you see what I am missing here?

Thanks

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

The way you have implemented will try to deserialize data into Items class. But it doesn't have the required properties to deserialize. When you need to get a list of data through rest template exchange, you can get them as follows.

1. Get data as an array and convert it into arrayList.

   ```
   Item[] itemArray = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Item[].class).getBody();

   List<Item> itemList = Arrays,asList(itemArray);
   ```

or

2. Use ParameterizedTypeReference to get data as a list

   ```
   ResponseEntity<List<Item>> itemList = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Item>>() {});

   List<Item> itemList = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Item>>() {}).getBody(); // access list directly
   ```

Comment: Items class is not required.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to add this to your ObjectMapper:

`mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);`

And on your entity add `@JsonRootName("item")`